# Can I turn the hard key lights on from an app?

Tags: android

That pretty much sums it up - I want to write an app that will work with the lights of the hard keys/buttons on my phone. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's no formal API for doing this in android proper, but your specific phone might have one. What kind of of phone do you have?